# Excel Formula - VLOOKUP leave blank if no lookup value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet in which the VLOOKUP process I'm trying to do is getting more convoluted, but I'd like to try to see if this is possible.

I have the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,DataTable,4,FALSE),"Value Not Found")
```

This works perfectly for looking up a set of data by pasting the values into column A. This looks to see if the value is found in the table called "DataTable" and returns the value in the 4th index.

What I'm now trying to do is paste this formula all the way down the excel spreadsheet. However, this results in every cell to say "Value Not Found" even though there is no lookup value in column A. Is there a way to alter this formula to leave the cell blank if the respective cell in column A is blank?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(A2="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,DataTable,4,FALSE),"Value Not Found"))
```

Comment: Thank you. So simple.... don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Tony probably take out the IFERROR part and "Value Not Found" as well.

Comment: @Edward, I would want to keep it because that determines that if the lookup value doesn’t exist in the table, then instead of showing the #N/A error, it shows Value Not Found.